Check the google smarthome action enabled status for a user?
Is it possible to check the user account linking or action linked status for a specific user at any given time?
Example: Something like which Alexa provides enablement-api
Purpose: We are implementing App Flip for both smart-assistant (alexa skill and google smarthome actions) and plan to display the linked account status in the UI for each user. While the Alexa API works seamlessly for this, I haven't found a similar API for Google Actions to retrieve the linked status.

While Google doesn't provide APIs to check for enablement, you can generally assume that a Google Action is enabled for the user unless a disconnect intent is sent.
Here are two important scenarios to consider:

Partner Notification: If a partner informs Google that they want to invalidate a connection, Google will promptly act on that request.
User Notification: If a Google user indicates that they no longer wish to maintain this connection, Google will notify the partner to invalidate it accordingly.

To further assess account linking status, you may verify linked accounts by checking specific user data. If the user has granted consent, you can indirectly verify linked account status by checking for specific user data or tokens required by your action. For example, if your action needs access to the user's Google Calendar, checking for calendar permissions can confirm the linkage.
